# Mysql query to return rows containing a specific word

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a table called Publisher and a column in that table called Publisher_Name. I want to return all names that have the word "and" in them, but not individual words with "and" as a sequence within a word. For example I want to return "Thames and Hudson" but not "Random House".

This is the only way I know to return a phrase with a specific word.

```
SELECT PUBLISHER_NAME
FROM PUBISHER
WHERE PUBLISHER_NAME LIKE '%and%';
```

The above statement though will return things like "Random House"

How can I edit this statement to return only what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using REGEXP

```
SELECT PUBLISHER_NAME
FROM PUBISHER
WHERE PUBLISHER_NAME REGEXP '[[:<:]]and[[:>:]]';
```

This seems to work, with help of Barmar changing the Regex to something MySQL does accept :)

Comment: Seriously... it was that simple. I searched online forever and couldn't find anything that said that. Thank you so much.

Comment: i'm guessing if the last word is and you want it as well?

Comment: MySQL doesn't use PCRE escape sequences. Use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.

Comment: @Barmar aaah, i was just trying my code, good to know ^^ haven't used regexp inside mysql much before.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `MATCH...AGAINST` but your `PUBLISHER_NAME` field should be in a `FULLTEXT index`

You can find some information **[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)**

Your query would look like:

```
SELECT PUBLISHER_NAME
FROM PUBISHER
WHERE MATCH (PUBLISHER_NAME)
AGAINST ('and' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on that column than you can search for individual words. If you use that solution, make sure you change the minimum indexed word length ([ft_min_word_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) or [innodb_ft_min_token_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size)) to 3 or lower and override the default stopword list ([ft_stopword_file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file) or [innodb_ft_enable_stopword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_enable_stopword)  to remove the word "and" and any other common words you want to index.

If you want to use your approach, you can try something like this, but it will be slow because it was to do a table scan:

```
SELECT PUBLISHER_NAME
FROM PUBISHER
WHERE PUBLISHER_NAME LIKE '% and %'
OR PUBLISHER_NAME LIKE 'and %'
OR PUBLISHER_NAME LIKE '% and';
```

Comment: Your query will still match `random house`. You need to take out `%and%`.

Comment: @Barmar you are right. I forgot the spaces. Fixed now. Thanks!